# Find out if two numbers are close based on the dataset

Tags: java, statistics, comparison

I do not know how to approach the problem of finding out if two numbers are "similar"/close to each other, based on a dataset.

For example to find out if value 1 is similar to value 3, based on the dataset {1,2,3,4,5}.

What are some statistical approaches to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can write a for loop. When passing the first number, you set a boolean to true. If this boolean in true, you will increase the 'simelar-factor'. You can end this loop when passing the second number using 'break'